# Картинка выходит за пределы блока

Tags: html, css

Картинка profile-avatar выходит за контейнер в котором находится, как будто с абсолютным позиционированием.

[image: Через консоль]
[image: Просто]

HTML

```
<div className="profile">
       <div className="profile-container">
           <div className='profile-about-left'>
               <div className='profile-about-left-container visual-container'>
                   <img className='profile-avatar' src={photo} alt='avatar'/>
                   <button className='profile-editButton button'>Edit</button>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div className="profile-about-right">
               <div className='profile-about-right-container visual-container'>
                   <div className="profile_user-info">
                       <span className='profile-user-info_name'>{state.fullName}</span>
                       <ProfileStatus userId={state.userId} userOwnerId={userOwnerId}
                       status={status} updateProfileStatus={updateProfileStatus}/>
                   </div>
                   <div className="profile_user-job">
                       <span className='profile-lookJob'>{state.lookingForAJob}</span>
                       <span className='profile-jobDescription'>{jobDescription}</span>
                   </div>
                   <div>
                       <button className='profile-about-more button'>Show More</button>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.profile {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 2%;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.profile-container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;

}

.profile-about-right {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

.profile-about-right-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 2%;
}

.profile-avatar {
    height: 8em;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.profile-about-left {
    height: 100%;
}

.profile-about-left-container {
    padding: 10%;
}
```

Comment: картинке надо задавать адаптивную ширину, типа "max-width: 100%" (если она больше блока) или просто "width: 100%". а вот высоту задавать картинке - так себе идея

Comment: Вроде так банально но уже долгое время не мог решить. Ваш комментарий помог спасибо !